# Why do the number of flags change?

Tags: bug, flags

When  I go to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools, I see three flags (a 3 by the flags tab).

When I go to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=flags&daterange=last7days, I only see two (a 2 by the flags tab).

When I go back, it toggles back to 3.

Why does it do that?

Comment: Looks like caching.

Comment: @Mołot Caching. It's always caching...